# Getting rid of certain characters in a string in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have characters in the middle of a string that I want to get rid of. These characters are `=`, `p`,, and `H`. Since they are not the leftmost and the rightmost characters in the string, I cannot use `strip()`. Is there a function that gets rid of a certain character in any location in a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual tool for this job is `str.translate`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

```
>>> 'hello=potato'.translate(None, '=p')
'hellootato'
```

Comment: Is translate better than replace?

Comment: Since you need to remove multiple characters, yes.

Comment: @wim But would the order have to be `=p`? I suspect this would not remove `p=`.

Comment: Note that `translate` works differently in Python 3.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I use `2.7`, which I forgot to mention. But thank you for the note :)

Comment: It also works differently on unicode objects it python 2.7, so watch out for that

Answer (score 2):

Check the .replace() function:

```
> 'aaba'.replace('a','').replace('b','')
< ''
```

Answer (score 1):

My usual tool for this is the regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> invalidCharacters = r'[=p H]'
>>> mystring = re.sub(invalidCharacters, '', ' poH==hHoPPp p')
'ohoPP'
```

If you need to constrain the number (i.e., the count) of characters you remove, see the `count` argument.